# Dropdown list to be shown on button click with same button on each table row

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a Book management page for which i have, on each table row, the same button. I managed to change it in a dropdown list in jquery but this works only for the button of the first row. I could notre make it work for the other rows. Can i have some help

```
<body>
    <?php
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bibliotheque;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Erreur de connexion ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    {
        echo'connection ok';
   }
//On récupère tout le contenu de la table livres
    $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM `livres`");
    ?>
    <!--Creation d'une table avec un en-tete en html-->
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Titre du livre</th>
                <th>Prénom auteur</th>
                <th>Nom  auteur :</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
//On cree une requête qui va rechercher chaque entree de la table Livres et on la place dans une colonne du tableau
        while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()) {
            ?>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['id_livre']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['titre']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['prenom_auteur']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $donnees['nom_auteur']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="db/suppression.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $donnees['id'] ?>"/>
                            <input type="submit" name="valider" class="delete" value="Supprimer" />
                            <input type="button" name="pret" id="pret" value="pret" />
                        <select id="personnes" name="personnes" hidden="hidden">
                            <option value="personnes">People 1</option>
                            <option value="personnes">People 2</option>
                            <option value="personnes">People 3</option>
                            <option value="personnes">People 4</option>
                        </select>

                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            $reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Show some code maybe?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is to click on the button with id `pret` and get an dropdown list so I can select the people whom I want to lend the book to. in JQuery i was able to get the button of the first row (first book of the table) clickable and transformed to a dropdown list but the other are not working

Comment: my jQuery code is the following : 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pret').on('click', function(){
        $('#personnes').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Je viens de trouver une solution qui me convient parfaitement en jQuery :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var pret = $('.pret'), personnes = $('.personnes');
    $(pret).each(function(){
        $(this).on ('click', function(){
          $(this).next().slideToggle();
            $(personnes).hide();

        });
    });
});
```